# I can't comment in the Review Queue, can you?

Tags: bug, review

For a while I've been unable to <strike>be able to rant</strike> comment in the review queue... any review queue... well except the "suggested edit" queue... anyone experiencing this issue as well?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr7rN.png]

Ah, btw, reproducible in Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed soon.  It's also a duplicate: [Why are comments now disabled on the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews)